# Softlayer API subnet Type

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm having issues figuring out using the python Softlayer API to get the subnetlist  "Type" if is Portable/Public. None of the values returned seem to show it.

Could anyone share how to find that ?

Let me know if I haven't supplied sufficient information.

Comment: What is the big picture? Are you just trying to figure out which subnets are primary vs secondary?

Comment: No, I actually need to know what's the network type in order to display that subnet some place else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More then just the answer can be fund here:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-1

This is a good tutorial in how to use Softlayer's API with python.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The addressSpace property displasy if the subnet is private or public. You can see more information here: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet 
But I did not found a property which displays if the subnet is portable.

Regards

Comment: I've seen 2 differences that might help identify. 
1) values returned from query are Primary when the subnet list has a key hardware
2) anything that contains Primary under subnetType, others seem to be Portable

But not sure with any of this!

Comment: That's true, it dose not say if it's Primary or Portable,

Comment: That's true, it dose not say if it's Portable, 
if subnetType contains SECONDARY_ON_VLAN then it's portable, at least that's the rule we are following.